# How to call "city name" from Country object?

Tags: java

`city.getCityName()` and `country.getCountry()` would work. But how to get `cityname` using `country` object? Like `country.getCity().getCityName()`? 
And when `country.getCity` is called it is returning `null`.

```
public class Main {

class Country  {

    private String countryName;
    private City city;

    public String getCountry(){
        return countryName;
    }
    public void setCountry(String countryName){
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public City getCity(){
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(City city){
        this.city = city;
    }
}

class City {

    private String cityName;

    public String getCityName(){
        return cityName;
    }
    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    City city = new City();
    city.setCityName("Chittoor");

    Country country = new Country();
    country.setCountry("INDIA");

    System.out.println("how to get cityName using country object");
}

}
```

Comment: You never set a `City` on `country`...

Comment: I don't understand please tell me how to do it

Comment: `country.setCity(city)`? After that `country.getCity` should not return `null`

Comment: The problem stated above tell you the relation between `Country` and `Ctiy` is incorrect. A `City` is in one `Country`, a `Country` have multiple `City`. For the rest, I don't see what is your question exactly. Is it about the `null` ? Then you need to set `city` in `Country`. If not, please rephrase.

Comment: If you can tell that `City` is not always set on your `Country` isntance, then you should check if it is `null` first. Example: `System.out.println(country.getCity()!=null ? country.getCity().getCityName() : "No city set");`

Comment: thanks it worked @XtremeBaumer

Answer (score 1):

A possibile solution could be something like that:

```
if(mycountry.getCity() != null){
    mycountry.getCity().getCityName();
}
```

Another solution is make the method getCity() return an `Optional<City>`. In this case the previous code becomes:

```
 Optional<City> optionalCity = mycountry.getCity();
 if(optionalCity.isPresent()){
    optionalCity.get().getCityName();
 }
```

You can find information about Optional [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: I would do a `optionalCity.map(City::getCityName).orElse(null)` personally. `orElse`, `orElseThrow`, ... based on the need.

Comment: @AxelH I would do the same thing but I think he's very new to programming so I'd keep the solution simple.

Comment: Agreed to keep it "simple"  but `Optional` might be already to much ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the object of city in country class using setCity method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

City city = new City();
city.setCityName("Chittoor");

Country country = new Country();
country.setCountry("INDIA");
country.setCity(city);//setting the city

System.out.println("how to get cityName using country object");
System.out.println(country.getCity().getCityName());//printing the city
}

}
```